# Inverse function of lodash's _.invertBy()

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

What is the inverse function of lodash's `_.invertBy()` method?

I want to do a roundtrip and convert an object later to the same form after inverting it. But if I do

```
> _.invertBy({apple: 'fruit', pear: 'fruit'})
{ fruit: [ 'apple', 'pear' ] }
> _.invertBy({ fruit: [ 'apple', 'pear' ] })
{ 'apple,pear': [ 'fruit' ] }
```

and `{ 'apple,pear': [ 'fruit' ] }` is not the same as `{apple: 'fruit', pear: 'fruit'}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can hack the the source code of `invertBy` from [github](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/invertBy.js) and come up with something like

```js
function invertBackBy(object, iteratee = _.identity) {
  const result = {}
  Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
    object[key].map(iteratee).forEach((value) => {
      result[value] = key
    })
  })
  return result
}
```

or if a lodash one-liner is what you wanted, I think there's nothing *much simpler* than

```js
oinv => _.reduce(oinv, (acc, values, key) => 
   _.assign(acc, _.fromPairs(_.map(values, value => [value, key]))), {})
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d5ow6eym/) for an example.